# how can I view a variable name from a given address from t32 cmm script?

Tags: trace32

how can I view a variable name from a given address from t32 cmm script ?
I have address and want to log the name of the variable from T32 loaded dump or elf ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the variable name by the address with PRACTICE function `sYmbol.Name(<addr>)`.

E.g.: If variable "myvar" is at address D:0x100 you can get the name again from the address with

```
PRINT sYmbol.Name(D:0x100)
```

or assign it to a macro like this

```
&name=sYmbol.Name(D:0x100)
```